# Upgrade Samsung Galaxy S2 to Jelly Bean

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

What is the easiest way to upgrade my Galaxy S2 to Android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean? Also, how do I update it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some ways to update your firmware, from easiest to harder (not necessarily hardest).

1. OTA (Over the air) update. Trigger it via `Settings > About > Software update`.
2. [Kies](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/SWUP/JSP). Install Kies on your PC, run Kies, and connect your mobile phone to your PC using USB cable. There is an update function in the Kies software.
3. [Odin (Windows)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18475/what-is-the-odin-tool). This is a 3rd-party tool that you use to flash (or install, in layman's terms) a stock (or default) ROM or custom ROM on your phone. You will need to download [Odin](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2189539) and the custom ROM or [stock ROM](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/) from somewhere. There are several guides on Google on how to flash a stock / custom ROM for Samsung Galaxy S2. For Linux, you can use Heimdall.

Comment: Thanks for your answer:
for the first option i have tried it and it tell me that no updates even i have android 2 in my galaxy S2
, for the second option I need to upgrade to the unofficial android 4.2 
I think the last one is the best; but have you try it, it is working without any problems ?

Comment: @HananAwwad See if this answer helps you: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/27871/5342 Let me know if it works.

Comment: I don't think; what i need this a reliable way to upgrade my galaxy s2(GT-19100) from android 2.3.3 to android 4.2

Comment: Jelly Bean 4.2.2 is not yet released for the Samsung Galaxy S2. ([Source](http://au.ibtimes.com/articles/487286/20130708/samsung-galaxy-s2-ends-android-4-2.htm#.UeOs6m37Da9))

Comment: what about Android 4.1.2

Comment: Thank you all i got what i need, This tutorial helped me a lot http://droidfirmwares.com/vjms4-android-4-1-2-jelly-bean-official-firmware-for-galaxy-s2-i9100.html